# Nested withUnsafeBytes calls unavoidable?

Tags: swift

I wrote some code in Swift for a data manipulation method (bridged from Obj-C / C code) that takes 3 `UnsafeRawBufferPointer`s and it looks like this

```
    data1.withUnsafeBytes({ (rawDataPtr1) -> Void in
        data2.withUnsafeBytes({ (rawDataPtr2) -> Void in
            data3.withUnsafeBytes({ (rawDataPtr3) -> Void in

                doTheThing(rawDataPtr1, rawDataPtr2, rawDataPtr3)

            })
        })
    })
```

That's a lot of unsightly code to do what you can pretty much do in one line in Obj-C or C++. Is there any alternative to all this nesting?

Comment: can you provide original function declaration in `ObjC/C`?

Comment: @user28434 Happy to, although I don't see that it should bear any influence on any answers so I'll just put it here in the comment, and for simplicity let's assume I can't change it: `+ (void) doTheThing:(uint8_t*) array1 array2:(uint8_t*) array2 array3:(uint8_t*) array3`.

Comment: Note I also had to call `.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)` 3 times (on each rawDataPtr) to use that method - more stuff I omitted from the question for clarity.

Comment: can you wrap this function in some other function accepting `NSArray *`? Just for sake of interfacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any alternative to all this nesting?

In general, probably not. The buffer pointer is unsafe. For every unsafe buffer pointer, therefore, you need a confined context in which it is guaranteed to remain accessible. That's what the closure is. You have three such pointers so you need three such contexts, nested; that's what the nest of closures is. You could notate your way out of this, perhaps, but it's not worth the effort. "Unsightly" is in the mind of the beholder, in any case; your code looks normal and pleasant to me.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much, worth a shot though ;-) Maybe future answers will come along for future versions of Swift and be helpful/interesting...